# Alternative to sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am attempting to run [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-grid-search-text-feature-extraction-py) from sklearn to better understand their `TfidfTransformer` from `sklearn.feature_extraction.text`. However, I am returned with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grid_search_text_feature_extraction.py", line 16, in <module>
    from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
ImportError: No module named model_selection
```

After initial searching I see that model_selection is available only beginning with version 0.18. I am currently running version 0.16.1 and am unable to update the package myself due to network config that I am working in. From [iPython (python 2) - ImportError: No module named model_selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39820893/ipython-python-2-importerror-no-module-named-model-selection) I see that the predecessor to `sklearn.model_selection` was `sklearn.cross_validation`, however there is no GridSearchCV available.

What quick alternative is there to utilize GridSearchCV or replace it completely to run [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-grid-search-text-feature-extraction-py)?

Comment: You can access gridsearchCV from sklearn.grid_search in 0.16. See http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grid_search_text_feature_extraction.py", line 16, in <module>
    from sklearn.cross_validation import gridsearchCV 
ImportError: cannot import name gridsearchCV`

Looks like `from sklearn.cross_validation import gridsearchCV` does not work?

Comment: I edited my comment. It's in grid_search not cross_validation. That's what I get for answering before double checking the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is from the url : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-grid-search-text-feature-extraction-py

To see the version of the example for an earlier version of scikit, simply replace **stable** in the url with the version you want so for example:
http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-grid-search-text-feature-extraction-py